# Why is the "invoke-command" run time so different on those two PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I need to pull some information from clients with the "invoke-command" and began writing the script to query computers from AD, put them into a variable, use the variable to check which computers are online or offline, put the status into hashtable and then run the invoke-command only on online computers. As working on this I thought it might be easier not to use the hashtable, instead do a foreach + test-connection just before excecution of the invoke-command. So I cloned and re-wrote. Both scripts are now finished and I'm wondering why the "invoke-command" is so much slower when ran after an "ForEach + Test-connection" loop whereas on my other script it's only half the time. In addition the -ErrorVariable also doesn't work. Here's what I mean:

```
Measure-Command {
#########################################################################################
# Check Computerstatus and put into hashtable
#########################################################################################
$computerstatus = @{}
ForEach ($computer in $adcomputers) {
  $result = Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -quiet
     If ($result) {$computerstatus.add( $computer, 'online')}
          else {$computerstatus.add( $computer, 'offline')}
 }
# Read hashtable and set Online/Offline variable:
$computersonline = Foreach ($Key in ($computerstatus.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq "online"})) {$Key.name}
$computersoffline = Foreach ($Key in ($computerstatus.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object {$_.Value -eq "offline"})) {$Key.name}

#########################################################################################
# Now run the invoke-command on online computers
#########################################################################################
$remotequery = Invoke-command -ComputerName $computersonline -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable MyErrorVar4InvCmd -scriptblock {remote-command}  | select Property | where Property -match 'True'
$cantaccess = $MyErrorVar4InvCmd.TargetObject

} # end measure-command
```

TotalSeconds      : 34,9779497 and " $cantaccess = $MyErrorVar4InvCmd.TargetObject" is correctly displayed

And the other, slow, approach:

```
Measure-Command {
#########################################################################################
# Now run the invoke-command
#########################################################################################
$queryresult = @()     # create blank array, it will get filled with +=
$CompOFFLINE = @()
ForEach ($computer in $adcomputers) {
  if (Test-Connection $computer -Count 1 -quiet) {
       $remotequery = Invoke-command -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable MyErrorVar4InvCmd -scriptblock {remote-command} | select Property | where Property -match 'True'
        if ($remotequery.Property -eq 'true') {
           $queryresult += $computer
        }
        else {
               }
  }
    else {
    $CompOFFLINE += $computer
    }
}

$cantaccess = $MyErrorVar4InvCmd.TargetObject

} # end measure-command
```

TotalSeconds      : 107,4585155 and the "$cantaccess = $MyErrorVar4InvCmd.TargetObject" is blank ...

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: the 2nd is slow because you are using `+=` on an array. that builds a NEW array each time you add to it ... arrays are _fixed size_, so adding to one requires building a new, larger one.

Comment: you can speed things up a good deal by using the `-Computer` parameter of `Invoke-Command` ... it accepts a collection of computer names and a scriptblock to run on those systems ... **_in parallel_**.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. as for the speed suggestion: I'm already running against an array (in $adcomputers) of computers ;)

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// your `ForEach ($computer in $adcomputers)` does not run things _in parallel_. it runs them one at a time - and it runs them locally. if you use `Invoke-Command` and feed the list of systems to it _as a list_ ... **_you will run the scriptblocks in parallel and on the target systems_**. that will gain a great deal of speed if you have any significant number of systems to work with. [*grin*]

Comment: ah I see what you mean now. Thanks :)

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]